# snap cannot access locale

Tags: snap, locale

While creating a snap, I kept getting an error like:
`locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory`.

In my `snapcraft.yaml`, I added `locales` to `build-packages` but no luck.

I tried `$ snap run --shell mysnap` and the first line is a warning:

`bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)`

Comment: Does [this](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snapping-neofetch/877/2?u=ads20000) help?